# Get a Tag Attribute Value when Tab is active

Tags: javascript, html, function, attributes, tags

I am trying to retrieve the value inside a Tag if the Tab is active.

The Tag goes like this :

```
<li class="top-tab" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true"> TITLE OF SECTION </li>
```

I want to retrieve the Value "**true**" of the attribute **"aria-selected"**.

My final goal is to fire a tag (GTM) to get the **Title of section** when Tab is active (hence attribute is true).

I tried this :

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("top-tab")[0].Attr("aria-selected").value("true").textContent
```

Note : I cannot access the html source to modify elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below will get the inner text of the first element with class ".top-tab" and aria-selected attribute "true"

```
var elementInnerText = document.querySelector(".top-tab, [aria-selected=true]").innerText;
```

Comment: Working fine... Thx

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("aria-selected")[0].getAttribute("aria-selected")
```

This will return the value of that attribute inside the `top-tab` tag.

You can use this value to then evaluate if you want to get the inner test of the `<li>` with the following.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("top-tab")[0].innerText
```

Comment: It is working... I should have know the "getAttribute". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To get all tags that have area-selected="true"

```
var selected  = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-selected="true"]');
```

Then get the inner html of the element

```
selected[0].innerHTML;
```

I am not sure why you need to get them by class. Do you have the "area-selected" attribute on other elements? If not, then the code above should work just fine for you,

Comment: "aria-selected" is present for all other tabs... "false" for non-active tab and true" for the active tabs.